# Comparing value with same period last month in Google Data Studio

Tags: datetime, looker-studio

I'm trying to compare `Transactions` **This Month** with `Transactions` during the **Same Period Last Month**.

However, when comparing against `Previous Period` it seems to compare against the entire **Last Month** (which is technically the **Previous Period**).

How would I go about comparing it to the same period last month instead? I've tried to look for a formula/function I could use when creating a new field, but I couldn't find any functions where I can specify a date range.

I thought about creating a new field where I divide the `Transactions` of **Last Month** (no idea how to get that number through a function though), divide it by the amount of days in a month and times it by the number of days passed in this month. But this wouldn't create a fair representation of last month's `Transactions` until that day.

Answer (score 5):

## Update: Complete Process with a Date Range Control

### 1) [Date Range Control](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6291067)

Add the component and set the Date Range to `This Month to Date`

### 2) [Time Series Chart](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7059697)

- Add the Chart
- Set the Date Range to Auto (default)
- Set the Comparison Date Range to `Previous Period`

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/f42f6afe-d21f-4cec-a037-6ba5ac0f9376/page/6wEuB) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

## Original Post: View Mode

The ability to set a *Rolling Date Range* was introduced in the [3rd October 2018 Update](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9489310). Adding a GIF to demonstrate the use of *Month-to-Date* with the *Comparison Date Range* set to *Previous Period* ([Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/f42f6afe-d21f-4cec-a037-6ba5ac0f9376)).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Date range comparisons are unfortunately pretty difficult beyond the default "vs previous period" and "vs previous year".

The only way I've gotten around this is to add a new metric to your data source which is (in your example) the value from a month previous. I've never found a way to do it within Data Studio itself.

Not ideal.

Comment: Hmm okay. The data source I'm using at the moment is Google Analytics, I don't think it's possible to add such a metric to that source. Thanks for the clarification though!

Comment: No it's not. Annoying really.

There's a lot of feature requests for this so you might want to visit the following link and star the relevant ones.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=data%20studio%20date%20comparison

Answer (score -1):

the way i try to solve it, is creating a Date range for each period and group the data range with the data you want. (ie: last week, last month, last year compare a data range pediod -> you have to create 3 Date Range Groups data).

Comment: Its better to write a code example as answer. Now its marked and flagged as "comment"; which means that your help might be voted for deletion due to lack of example code/solution.